# How to remove the word "Chapter" from the heading in ebook: tex4ebook

Tags: chapters, tex4ht, tex4ebook, ebook, epub

I am compiling an ebook in Kannada and I would like to remove the word "Chapter" from the heading in the ebook.

The output of ebook as shown in the first image [image: Output of ebook]. However, I would want it look like in the second image [image: Required output]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and how the chapter header is generated at present: via a `\chapter` instruction, a `\chapter*` instruction, of by some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you can just change the `\chaptername` macro in a `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\let\chaptername\relax
\EndPreamble
```

This works normally, but not with this example I found:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[justified,12.5pt]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\def\linenumberfont{\normalfont}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[Script=Kannada]{Tunga}%{NudiUni01K.ttf}
\setmainlanguage{kannada}


\begin{document}
%\let\chaptername\relax

\chapter{ಪೀಠಿಕೆ}
ಆಧುನಿಕ ಬದುಕಿನ ಜ್ಞಾನ ವಿಜ್ಞಾನ ಕ್ಷೇತ್ರದಲ್ಲಿನ ಅದ್ಭುತ ಅವಿಷ್ಕಾರಗಳಲ್ಲೊಂದಾದ ಮಾಹಿತಿ ತಂತ್ರಜ್ಞಾನದ ಒಂದು ವಿನೂತನ ಪರಿಕಲ್ಪನೆ  ವಿಕಿಪೀಡಿಯಾ. ಹವಾಮಿ ಭಾಷೆಯಲ್ಲಿ ವಿಕಿ
ಎಂದರೆ ಶೀಘ್ರ ಅಥವಾ ತ್ವರಿತಗತಿ ಎಂದರ್ಥ. ಇಂಗ್ಲೀಷಿನಲ್ಲಿ ಎನ್ ಸೈಕ್ಲೊಪೀಡಿಯಾ ಎಂದರೆ ವಿಶ್ವಕೋಶ ಎಂದರ್ಥ. ಇವೆರಡೂ ಶಬ್ದಗಳನ್ನು ಸಂಯೋಜಿಸಿ 
ವಿಕಿಪೀಡಿಯಾ ಎಂಬ ಗಣಕೀಕೃತ ವಿಶ್ವಕೋಶದ ಮಾದರಿಯಲ್ಲಿ ಇದನ್ನು ಅಭಿವೃದ್ಧಿಗೊಳಿಸಲಾಗಿದೆ. ಕನ್ನಡದಲ್ಲಿ ಇದನ್ನು 'ತ್ವರಿತ ವಿಶ್ವಕೋಶ' ಎಂದು ಹೆಸರಿಸ ಬಹುದು. 
ಇದೊಂದು ಬಹುಭಾಷೀಯ ಹಾಗೂ ಅಂತರ್ಜಾಲ ಆಧಾರಿತ ವಿಶ್ವಕೋಶವಾಗಿದ್ದು,ನಿರಂತರವಾಗಿ ಪರಿಷ್ಕರಣಗೂಳ್ಳಬಲ್ಲ ಮಾಹಿತಿ ವಿತರಣ ಸಾಧನವಾಗಿದೆ.

\end{document}
```

I guess that the chapter name is set by Polyglossia at the begin document, so it overwrites our redefinition.

Anyway, as you want also to change the chapter number, it is easiest to use a `make4ht` build file. Save the following code as `mybuild.lua`:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"
local number_table = {
  ["0"] = "೦",
  ["1"] = "೧",
  ["2"] = "೨",
  ["3"] = "೩",
  ["4"] = "೪",
  ["5"] = "೫",
  ["6"] = "೬",
  ["7"] = "೭",
  ["8"] = "೮",
  ["9"] = "೯",
  
}


local process = domfilter {
  function(dom)
    -- remove <br> elements from chapter
    for _, br in ipairs(dom:query_selector "h2 br") do
      local space = br:create_text_node(" ")
      br:replace_node(space)
    end
    -- -- remove text from chapter mark and convert numbers
    for _, mark in ipairs(dom:query_selector ".titlemark") do
      local titlemark = mark:get_text() or ""
      local number = titlemark:match("([%d%.]+)") or ""
      -- replace arabic number to kannada number
      local newnumber = number:gsub("%d", number_table)
      -- crete new HTML mode
      -- add space that will separate number from rest of the chapter title
      local numbernode = mark:create_text_node(newnumber .. " ")
      -- replace old text
      mark._children = {numbernode}
    end
    dom:traverse_elements(function(el)
      for _, child in ipairs(el:get_children()) do
        if child:is_text() then
          -- replace numbers in all texts
          child._text = child._text:gsub("%d", number_table)
        end
      end
    end)
    return dom
  end

}

Make:match("html$", process)
```

We use LUaXML DOM library to process HTML, find all chapter numbers and convert it to the correct form.

This is the result:

[image]

Compile using

```
tex4ebook -e mybuild.lua -x filename.tex
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried with my file and still getting the same output. I can share the actual files with you if required.

Comment: @ShastriD yes, I will need your actual file, but just small example that shows only the chapter title and your used packages

Comment: Is it possible you can share your mail id and I can mail all the files ?

Comment: @ShastriD sure: michal.h21@gmail.com